# rails association proxy error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

[This error keeps displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUJM6.png)

So i have the association done actually has_many, belongs_to i have no idea why is this error showing up.

Restoraan.rb

```
class Restoraan < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :kichens
    has_many :atmospheres
    has_many :resto_imgs
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :resto_imgs, :kichens, :atmospheres
    #serialize :resto_type, :restoKitchen
end
```

Kichen.rb

```
class Kichen < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :restoraan, dependent: :destroy
end
```

When i do Restoraan.kichen in rails c i get a error

> NoMethodError: undefined method `kichen' for #<
>   Class:0x005648039a9038>

Answer (score 1):

First, You need an instance of `Restoraan`.  So either, you need to create one or pull an existing one, such as `Restoraan.first.kichens` (assuming a Restorran object exists in the db).

Notice the plural, as you have defined this as a `has_many` association. Also, you have to call this on an instance of `Restoraan`.

As for the view, your `@kichens` instance variable will contain an `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` which acts very similar to an array. You can then iterate over this in the view to display any properties of a `Kichen` object.

```
  <% @kichens.each do |kichen| %>
    <p><%= kichen.some_kichen_property %></p>
    <p><%= kichen.some_kichen_property %></p>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: i did a   [@kichens = Restoraan.first.kichens.where("active = 1")]  in the show action of restoraans_controller, the error still remains

Comment: How come you have that statement in the `[]` array brackets? Also, your getting the same error? `NoMethodError: undefined method 'kichen' for #< Class:0x005648039a9038>` with this?

Comment: sorry about that i do not know how to mark code in comments, i'v put []braces because it didn't let me paste the comment.

Comment: Okay, does this answer your question about the rails c.  If you run `Restoraan.first.kichens` does that work in the console? Also, can you post your `restorran` show view.

Comment: that's not an error, your printing out the collection proxy, you would have to iterate over it. Can you post your view when that is displayed?

Comment: oh i understood where my mistake was, im rendering it the wrong way , and thank you for the help i really appriciate it.